# R using apply/plyr with RQuantlib function

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data set in a data frame with the following information:

```
> head(rs1)
       dater adjStkPrice                optSym     expire strike   bid   ask unadjStkPrice daysLeft   pnl
1 2011-01-03      127.05 SPY   131221P00115000 2013-12-21    115 14.89 15.40        127.05     1083 319.5
2 2011-01-04      126.98 SPY   131221P00115000 2013-12-21    115 15.00 15.39        126.98     1082 328.4
3 2011-01-05      127.64 SPY   131221P00115000 2013-12-21    115 14.39 14.86        127.64     1081 287.2
4 2011-01-06      127.39 SPY   131221P00115000 2013-12-21    115 14.38 14.80        127.39     1080 278.7
5 2011-01-07      127.14 SPY   131221P00115000 2013-12-21    115 14.67 15.10        127.14     1079 300.2
6 2011-01-10      126.98 SPY   131221P00115000 2013-12-21    115 14.75 15.19        126.98     1076 303.4
```

I'm trying to get the implied volatility using the `AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility` function in the `RQuantLib` package.  The problem is that it seems to only take single sets of values:

```
> rs1$impVol <- AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility("put", rs1$ask,
+ rs1$adjStkPrice, rs1$strike, .02, .05, rs1$daysLeft/ 365, .4)$impliedVol
Error in AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility.default("put", rs1$ask, rs1$adjStkPrice,  : 
  expecting a single value
```

I think this is a spot for the `apply` function but I'm not sure if I'm using it properly:

```
> rs1$impVol <- apply(rs1, 1, AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility("put", rs1$ask,
+ rs1$adjStkPrice, rs1$strike, .02, .05, rs1$daysLeft/ 365, .4)$impliedVol)
Error in AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility.default("put", rs1$ask, rs1$adjStkPrice,  : 
  expecting a single value
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want  `rs1$daysleft/252`, not over 365.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure about that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Vectorize` or `mapply`.

```
Vectorize(AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility)(
  type="put", value=15:16, underlying=130:131, 
  strike=115, dividendYield=.02, riskFreeRate=.05, maturity=1, 
  volatility=.1
)

mapply(
  AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility,
  type="put", value=15:16, underlying=130:131, 
  strike=115, dividendYield=.02, riskFreeRate=.05, maturity=1, 
  volatility=.1
)
```

If you want to use `apply`, its third argument should be a function.
In addition, it would convert each row to a vector, 
which is problematic when some of the columns contain strings.

You could also use `sapply` on the row numbers, 
but it is just a loop in disguise, less readable than `mapply`.

```
sapply(
  seq_len(nrows(rs1)),
  function(i) AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility( 
    type="put", 
    value=rs1$ask[i],
   ... (add the other arguments)
  )
)
```

Comment: +1! Is there a difference in performance between `mapply` and `Vectorize`, or is the difference purely in the syntax. Which do you prefer?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: Since `Vectorize` is just a wrapper around `mapply`, the performance should be the same. When I just want to call the function, I find `mapply` more readable, but when I need a vectorized function (usually as an argument to another function, often `outer`), I use `vectorize`.